# Can I "click" a WinUI 3 Button from code?

Tags: c#, user-interface, button, datepicker, winui-3

I would like to programmatically cause a `Click` event to fire for a `Button` in a *WinUI 3* desktop app. I've seen lots of questions about how to deal with this on **SO** but the answers all involve invoking the handler (using commands or direct calls, etc.), instead of through firing the event on the `Button`.

This is a great choice if you actually have access to the handler, but what if you don't? What if the `Button` is embedded in a more complex control and the handler is internal and does some non-trivial (or unknown) additional processing?

For example, I recently tried to reformat the `DatePicker` control (which seems to have a mind of its own about size and placement of its constituent `TextBlock`s and `LoopingSelector`s). I tried rewriting `Style`s and deriving `Control`s, worked with `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride` - all the common approaches - but nothing worked. `DatePicker` clearly does formatting in code. I finally just hid the `Button` (`FlyoutButton`) `DatePicker` defines and added my own. But now I'd like my `Button` (`ReplacementFlyoutButton`) to invoke the same handler the original `FlyoutButton` did, thus  creating the proper `Flyout` and doing all the date localization, etc. for me. Overriding `OnApplyTemplate` in a derived class gives me access to the underlying `FlyoutButton` (in `DatePicker`):

```c#
protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();

    // Tree looks like:
    // this as DatePicker
    //  LayoutRoot as Grid
    //   HeaderContentPresenter as ContentPresenter
    //   FlyoutButton as Button
    //    FlyoutButtonGrid as Grid
    //     ContentPresenter as ContentPresenter
    //      FlyoutButtonContentGrid as Grid
    //       DayTextBlock as TextBlock
    //       MonthTextBlock as TextBlock
    //       YearTextBlock as TextBlock
    //       FirstPickerSpacing as Rectangle
    //       SecondPickerSpacing as Rectangle
    DayTextBlock = GetTemplateChild("DayTextBlock") as TextBlock;
    MonthTextBlock = GetTemplateChild("MonthTextBlock") as TextBlock;
    YearTextBlock = GetTemplateChild("YearTextBlock") as TextBlock;
    FirstPickerSpacing = GetTemplateChild("FirstPickerSpacing") as Rectangle;
    SecondPickerSpacing = GetTemplateChild("SecondPickerSpacing") as Rectangle;
    FlyoutButtonContentGrid = GetTemplateChild("FlyoutButtonContentGrid") as Grid;
    FlyoutButton = GetTemplateChild("FlyoutButton") as Button;
    _replacementFlyoutButton = GetTemplateChild("ReplacementFlyoutButton") as Button;

    if (_replacementFlyoutButton is not null) { _replacementFlyoutButton.Click += OnReplacementFlyoutButtonClick;}
    }
```

Is there any way to invoke the `Click` event on `DatePicker` or its `FlyoutButton` in `OnReplacementFlyoutButtonClick()`?

Thanks for any ideas.

(Just as a note, neither the DatePicker nor the FlyoutButton have a non-null ContextFlyout and FlyoutButton's Flyout is null.)

Comment: You can always use UI Automation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview

Comment: Very interesting but seems like a very expensive solution for what should be a simple task. Also, I couldn't find a _WinUI 3_ implementation anywhere (no reference for `AutomationElement`, for example).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "expensive", but you can use that from any .NET code, there's nothing specific you need with WinUI3, for example, you can add that type code to a button's Click event https://gist.github.com/smourier/fffb122dfdf887df4534015828dbc069

Comment: You are entirely correct @SimonMourier. My comment was based on the understanding that I would have to somehow "add" automation to my app. It turns out that _WinUI 3_ controls (and other frameworks) have **UI Automation** baked in - they already implement `AutomationPeer`s which can be used to interact with them.  Thanks for pointing me there, Simon.

Answer (score 1):

All credit goes to @SimonMourier who pointed out that **Microsoft UI Automation** makes this easy - thank you Simon.

I was unable to find a good, well structured introduction to the use of **UI Automation** in *WinUI 3* but, after looking over the documentation for the `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Automation.*`, and particularly `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Automation.Peers`, namespaces I realized that *WinUI 3* `Controls` already implement classes that expose them to **Microsoft UI Automation**. For my question, the relevant class is `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Automation.Peers.ButtonAutomationPeer` (please note the namespace for *WinUI 3*).

The modified code:

```c#
protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();

    _replacementFlyoutButton = GetTemplateChild("ReplacementFlyoutButton") as Button 
            ?? throw new ArgumentException("Missing ReplacementFlyoutButton in DatePickerEx");
    var FlyoutButton = GetTemplateChild("FlyoutButton") as Button 
                       ?? throw new ArgumentException("Missing FlyoutButton in DatePickerEx");
    _replacementButtonAutomationPeer = FrameworkElementAutomationPeer.FromElement(FlyoutButton) as ButtonAutomationPeer 
            ?? throw new ArgumentException("Missing ButtonAutomationPeer in DatePickerEx");
    _replacementFlyoutButton.Click += OnReplacementFlyoutButtonClick;
}

private void OnReplacementFlyoutButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    => _replacementButtonAutomationPeer.Invoke();
```

Clicking the `ReplacementFlyoutButton` will now `Invoke` the `FlyoutButton` in the `OnReplacementFlyoutButtonClick` event handler, as required.